# DataTable Multiple Selection

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to fetch First column's row value, though Multiple Row selection of a Datatable.

**I am referring this-**
https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

I have a Table with example as Id.
I am able to fetch Single row value,
But how do I concatenate Multiple row selection like a Checkbox?
Here is my Javascript code so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
            {
                var data;

                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    "lengthChange": false
                });

                $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
                {
                    data = table.row(this).data();

                    console.log(data[0]);


                     $(this).toggleClass('selected');

                } );
            });
```

Comment: use the select extension -> http://datatables.net/extensions/select/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Working

HTML CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


<button type="button" id="btnAll">button all</button>

<table id="example" class="display DataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td><td>$372,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Herrod Chandler</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>59</td><td>2012/08/06</td><td>$137,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Rhona Davidson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>55</td><td>2010/10/14</td><td>$327,900</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Colleen Hurst</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>39</td><td>2009/09/15</td><td>$205,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Quinn Flynn</td><td>Support Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2013/03/03</td><td>$342,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Charde Marshall</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>36</td><td>2008/10/16</td><td>$470,600</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Haley Kennedy</td><td>Senior Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>43</td><td>2012/12/18</td><td>$313,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>19</td><td>2010/03/17</td><td>$385,750</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Michael Silva</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>66</td><td>2012/11/27</td><td>$198,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Paul Byrd</td><td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td><td>New York</td><td>64</td><td>2010/06/09</td><td>$725,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Gloria Little</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>New York</td><td>59</td><td>2009/04/10</td><td>$237,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td><td>$132,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Dai Rios</td><td>Personnel Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>35</td><td>2012/09/26</td><td>$217,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jenette Caldwell</td><td>Development Lead</td><td>New York</td><td>30</td><td>2011/09/03</td><td>$345,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Yuri Berry</td><td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td><td>New York</td><td>40</td><td>2009/06/25</td><td>$675,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td><td>$106,450</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Doris Wilder</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>Sidney</td><td>23</td><td>2010/09/20</td><td>$85,600</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td><td>$1,200,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Gavin Joyce</td><td>Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>42</td><td>2010/12/22</td><td>$92,575</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jennifer Chang</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>Singapore</td><td>28</td><td>2010/11/14</td><td>$357,650</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Brenden Wagner</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>28</td><td>2011/06/07</td><td>$206,850</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Fiona Green</td><td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>48</td><td>2010/03/11</td><td>$850,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Shou Itou</td><td>Regional Marketing</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>20</td><td>2011/08/14</td><td>$163,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Michelle House</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Sidney</td><td>37</td><td>2011/06/02</td><td>$95,400</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Suki Burks</td><td>Developer</td><td>London</td><td>53</td><td>2009/10/22</td><td>$114,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Prescott Bartlett</td><td>Technical Author</td><td>London</td><td>27</td><td>2011/05/07</td><td>$145,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Gavin Cortez</td><td>Team Leader</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>22</td><td>2008/10/26</td><td>$235,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Martena Mccray</td><td>Post-Sales support</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>46</td><td>2011/03/09</td><td>$324,050</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Unity Butler</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>47</td><td>2009/12/09</td><td>$85,675</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Howard Hatfield</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>51</td><td>2008/12/16</td><td>$164,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hope Fuentes</td><td>Secretary</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>41</td><td>2010/02/12</td><td>$109,850</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vivian Harrell</td><td>Financial Controller</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>62</td><td>2009/02/14</td><td>$452,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Timothy Mooney</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>37</td><td>2008/12/11</td><td>$136,200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jackson Bradshaw</td><td>Director</td><td>New York</td><td>65</td><td>2008/09/26</td><td>$645,750</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Olivia Liang</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>Singapore</td><td>64</td><td>2011/02/03</td><td>$234,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bruno Nash</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>38</td><td>2011/05/03</td><td>$163,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Sakura Yamamoto</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>37</td><td>2009/08/19</td><td>$139,575</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Thor Walton</td><td>Developer</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2013/08/11</td><td>$98,540</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Finn Camacho</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>47</td><td>2009/07/07</td><td>$87,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Serge Baldwin</td><td>Data Coordinator</td><td>Singapore</td><td>64</td><td>2012/04/09</td><td>$138,575</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zenaida Frank</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>New York</td><td>63</td><td>2010/01/04</td><td>$125,250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zorita Serrano</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>56</td><td>2012/06/01</td><td>$115,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jennifer Acosta</td><td>Junior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>43</td><td>2013/02/01</td><td>$75,650</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cara Stevens</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>New York</td><td>46</td><td>2011/12/06</td><td>$145,600</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hermione Butler</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2011/03/21</td><td>$356,250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Lael Greer</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>London</td><td>21</td><td>2009/02/27</td><td>$103,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Jonas Alexander</td><td>Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>30</td><td>2010/07/14</td><td>$86,500</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Shad Decker</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>51</td><td>2008/11/13</td><td>$183,000</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Michael Bruce</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>Singapore</td><td>29</td><td>2011/06/27</td><td>$183,000</td></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
    var row = oTable.row(pos).data();
    console.log(row);
} );

$("#btnAll").on("click",function(){
     var oAll =[];
 $('#example tbody tr.selected').each(function(){
      var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
    var row = oTable.row(pos).data();
    oAll.push(row);
 });
    console.log(oAll);
    alert(oAll);
});

});
```

result https://jsfiddle.net/7kfmyw6x/2/

Comment: What I want to do is get the selected row data into some variable, Example - If you select the first two rows from your example, I want to get Airi Satou and Angelica Ramos in a variable. If I also select the 3rd row , I want to get Airi Satou, Angelica Ramos and Ashton Cox  in a variable..

Comment: ok you are able to fetch only the latest selected row, How to fetch multiple highlighted rows and not only one row?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje when you do click on the button 'btn All' return all rows selected

Comment: Can u post the code here? So I could give it a green tick ? :)

Comment: hey hi, sorry for the trouble, but how to capture an event on click of, say 1st column or 1st and 2nd column only?  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () will capture click of entire row right? I want a click event on only click of a particular column

Comment: If you want capture the event by column you can use  `$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function ()`@AniruddhaRaje